# Necesito registrar varios registros en una sola consulta sql en java con el patron MVC DAO y VO

Tags: java, mysql, mvc

A continuación verán una imagen donde hay dos variables que resive arrays desde el VO hasta ahí todo bien pero como pueden ver en la linea 59 y 60 me marca error se que falta algo pero no se muy bien que es solo quiero registrar en mi base de datos el id de mi citas junto al id de los servicios que contiene esta cita, ojala halla sido un poco claro y puedan ayudarme con este problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

````
public class CitaServicioDAO extends Conexion implements Crud {
    //1.Declarar objetos y variables

    private Connection conexion = null;
    private PreparedStatement puente = null;
    private ResultSet mensajero = null;

    //1.1.Declarar variable para cualquier metodo
    public boolean operaciones = false;
    public String sql;

    //1.2.Declarar las variables del VO
    public String  idCita [] , idServicio [];
     public String cisCosto = "";
    public CitaServicioDAO() {
    }

    //2.
    public CitaServicioDAO(CitaServicioVO cisVO) {
        super();

        try {
            conexion = this.obtenerConexion();
                idCita = cisVO.getIdCita();
                idServicio = cisVO.getIdServicio();
                cisCosto = cisVO.getCisCosto();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(CitaServicioDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean agregarRegistro() {
        try {
                sql = "INSERT INTO cita_servicio VALUES(?,?)";
                puente = conexion.prepareStatement(sql);
                puente.setString(1, idCita);
                puente.setString(2, idServicio);
                puente.addBatch();
                puente.executeBatch();
                operaciones = true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(CitaServicioDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        } finally {
            try {
                this.cerrarConexion();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Logger.getLogger(CitaServicioDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            }
        }
        return operaciones;
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Y esta otra también: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/21

Comment: No hay nada complejo la pregunta es facil de entender solo ahi un pequeño error

Comment: No se trata que sea fácil o difícil, se trata de seguir las reglas de cómo preguntar y pues, en los enlaces mostrados hay sugerencias para darle buena calidad a tu pregunta y también explicaciones por los votos negativos :)

Comment: Perdon soy nuevo en esto no tengo mucho conocimiento

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Si lo que se requiere es registrar una cita que contiene varios servicios, se deberá corregir la declaración para que reciba un solo idCita (String id_Cita) y no un arreglo.

Declaración:

```
public String id_Cita, id_Servicio[];
```

Al momento de insertar se recorre el array idServicio[]:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO cita_servicio VALUES(?,?)";
puente = conexion.prepareStatement(sql);
for(int i=0; i<idServicio.length; i++){
  puente.setString(1,idCita);
  puente.setString(2,idServicio[i]);
  puente.addBatch();
  puente.executeBatch(); 
}
operaciones = true;
```

Comment: Amigo pregunta la sentencia sql no debe de ir en el for?
Pasan dos cosas al momento, la primera es que si llega la matriz en la variable idServicio pero no registra en la base de datos

Comment: No estimado, la sentencia para realizar el insert va a ser la misma, lo que cambia son los parámetros que esta enviando para que se inserten en la tabla.
Sin embargo, el ponerla dentro del ciclo for no afecta en el proceso ya que en cada repetición siempre va a tener el mismo valor, seria algo innecesario.

Comment: tiene sentido usar el prepareStatement en cada vuelta? si el query es el mismo, no basta con limpiar parametros y pasarle nuevos?

Comment: Y otra cosa.. por nada del mundo pongas una respuesta atras de otra.. mira por favor [answer]. borra todas las respuestas que no correspondan. Si necesitas agregar algo, tenes el boton [edit] para hacerlo

Comment: vale entonces dejo la sentencia como esta pero ahora ya hice debug y algo no se esta realizando correctamente en el try catch  como te digo llega la matriz a la variable pero no me registra en la base de datos

Comment: @DavidSepulveda si esta respuesta te sirvió pero ahora no te funciona, por qué la aceptaste? La aceptaste sin probar?? Esta respuesta ejecuta el executeBatch tantas veces como hay conjuntos de datos a insertar; no es correcta